What is the maximum change in the angle between three points if each of the three points are subject to a perturbation up to epsilon?
I have a problem where I have three points in Euclidean space, say $\{\textbf{p1},\textbf{p2},\textbf{p3}\} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. I am looking to bound the change in the angle between the three points at $\textbf{p2}$. So for example, if we have the following vector definitions: $\textbf{u} = \textbf{p2}-\textbf{p1}$ and $\textbf{v} = \textbf{p3}-\textbf{p2}$, then the angle between the three points is
\begin{equation}
\theta = arccos\bigg(\frac{\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v}}{|\textbf{u}||\textbf{v}|}\bigg).
\end{equation}
The three points can move up to $\epsilon$, what is an upper limit for
\begin{equation}
|\theta' - \theta| = \bigg|arccos\bigg(\frac{\textbf{u}' \cdot \textbf{v}'}{|\textbf{u}'||\textbf{v}'|}\bigg) - arccos\bigg(\frac{\textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v}}{|\textbf{u}||\textbf{v}|}\bigg)\bigg|,
\end{equation}
where $\textbf{u}' = \textbf{p2}'-\textbf{p1}'$, $\textbf{v}' = \textbf{p3}'-\textbf{p2}'$ and $|\textbf{p1}'-\textbf{p1}|<\epsilon$, $|\textbf{p2}'-\textbf{p2}|<\epsilon$, $|\textbf{p3}'-\textbf{p3}|<\epsilon$?
Thank you in advance for any help - I've been stuck in this problem and can't make any headway. I've tried using the mean value theorem, although I'm not sure this solution is valid because $arccos$ is not continuous on the full closed interval $[0,180]$.
